# functions to call on resize and load as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started a project, and wondered if instead of what I usually do (write a load of functions and call them on resize and load as needed), if there is a cleaner/more efficient way of writing the following:

```
/**
 *  Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
 *  be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
 *  N milliseconds. If 'immediate' is passed, trigger the function on the
 *  leading edge, instead of the trailing.
 */
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;

        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };

        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
} // debounce()


/**
 * Mobile header menu, shown when browser < 768px (teen-bear see ./mixins/_breakpoints.scss)
 */
function mobileMenu(){
    jQuery('.c-primary-nav__level-1 > li > a').on('click', function(e){
        if( window.innerWidth <= 768 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            $this = jQuery(this);
            $this.parent().toggleClass('c-primary-nav__level-1--active');
            $this.next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
        }
    });

    jQuery('.c-primary-nav__level-2 > li > a').on('click', function(e){
        if( window.innerWidth <= 768 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            $this = jQuery(this);
            $this.parent().toggleClass('c-primary-nav__level-2--active');
            $this.next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
        }
    });

    // Show/hide mobile menu on mobiles
    jQuery('.c-header__burger').on('click', function(){
        jQuery('.c-header__burger').toggleClass('c-header__burger--active');
        jQuery('.c-header__burger-wrap').toggleClass('c-header__burger-wrap--active');
        jQuery('html').toggleClass('mobile-menu-active');
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav li').removeClass('c-primary-nav__level-1--active c-primary-nav__level-2--active');
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav ul').removeAttr('style');
    });

    // When overlay is clicked, close the mobile menu
    jQuery('.c-overlay').on('click', function(){
        jQuery('html').removeClass('mobile-menu-active');
        jQuery('.c-header__burger').removeClass('c-header__burger--active');
        jQuery('.c-header__burger-wrap').removeClass('c-header__burger-wrap--active');
    });
} // mobileMenu()


/**
 * Fixed header
 * Adds padding to body for mobiles when the header is fixed to the top of the 
 * browser
 */
function fixedHeader(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 768){
        jQuery('body').css("paddingTop","55px");
    } else {
        jQuery('body').css("paddingTop","0");
    }
}


/**
 * Footer mobile menu
 */
function footerMenu(){
    jQuery('.c-footer__column > h3').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('c-footer__column--active');
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.c-footer__column-expander').stop().slideToggle();
    });
}


function mobileMenuCleanup(){
    if( window.innerWidth > 768 ){

        // Mobile header menu cleanup
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav ul').removeAttr('style');
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav li').removeClass('c-primary-nav__level-1--active');
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav li').removeClass('c-primary-nav__level-2--active');
        jQuery('.c-primary-nav li').removeClass('c-primary-nav__level-3--active');
        jQuery('.c-header__burger').removeClass('c-header__burger--active');
        jQuery('.c-header__burger-wrap').removeClass('c-header__burger-wrap--active');
        jQuery('html').removeClass('mobile-menu-active');

        // Footer cleanup
        jQuery('.c-footer__column-expander').removeAttr('style');
        jQuery('.c-footer__column').removeClass('c-footer__column--active');
    }
} // mobileMenuCleanup()


requirejs(['jquery'], function(jQuery){ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        mobileMenu();
        footerMenu();
        fixedHeader();

        var browserResize = debounce(function() {
            mobileMenuCleanup();
            fixedHeader();
        }, 50);

        window.addEventListener('resize', browserResize);
    });
});
```

By the end of a project, my script.js file is normally full of functions, many are needed to be called on load and resize, and just thought if there is a better and more structured approach to do this. Things like shifting elements around the dom as required by design often results in a mess that is a pain to work through later down the line.

I'm not looking for someone to just completely rewrite the above (though feel free to do so!), but mainly just after some pointers and examples of a better approach to this.

Comment: @Incomputable Not sure I understand. Other than jQuery, which has already been added as a tag, I am using no other library/product. Functions here do different things, and I am looking for a best practice for writing/organising these example functions that allows for a clean organised code foundation later down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed Header**

I wonder why you actually need this. You can get rid of the JavaScript completely and do it using CSS only:

```
body {
    padding-top: 55px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

**Window Size/Breakpoint**

To adjust and maintain your code easier you can store the breakpoint in a variable and use it whenever needed:

```
var breakpoint = 768;

if (breakpoint < window.innerWidth) {}
```

Or you can create a variable that is set in `browserResize`:

```
var isMobile = false;

isMobile = breakpoint > window.innerWidth;

if (isMobile) {}
```

**Footer Menu**

Try to reduce DOM requests. For example you're creating jQuery objects and running `.parent()` twice on the same object:

```
jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass();
jQuery(this).parent().find();
```

If your markup is suitable you can refactor the code to:

```
jQuery('.c-footer__column').on('click', function(event) {
    if ('H3' == event.target.nodeName) {
        $(this).toggleClass('c-footer__column--active')
               .find('.c-footer__column-expander').stop().slideToggle();
    }
});
```

**Mobile Menu Cleanup**

Like said before, you can reduce the amount of DOM request. Here you can probably store the elements beforehand.

```
var primaryNavContainer = jQuery('.c-primary-nav ul'),
    primaryNavItems = primaryNavContainer.find('li');

function mobileMenuCleanup() {
    if (breakpoint window.innerWidth) {
        primaryNavContainer.removeAttr('style');
        primaryNavItems.removeClass('c-primary-nav__level-1--active c-primary-nav__level-2--active c-primary-nav__level-3--active');
    }
}
```

<sup>I didn't rewrite the whole thing, it's just to show you a way.</sup>

**Mobile Menu**

<sup>This last part is a shot in the dark, as I don't know anything about the actual markup and why classnames are like they are.</sup>

The first two event handler look very alike. To make it *DRY*, to get rid of complex class names like `__level-2` and to make this versatile for more than two levels of nesting, you could do something like this:

```
jQuery('.c-primary-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
    var e = jQuery(this),
        parent = e.parent(),
        submenu = e.next('ul');

    if (breakpoint >= window.innerWidth && submenu.length) {
        parent.toggleClass('active');
        submenu.stop().slideToggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Of course this will imply changes in your markup and CSS.

---

<sup>I wrote all code by heart, if you find mistakes, please add a comment.</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for this, will definitely make a few changes based on the above. The body padding was there as the header may change width and the value was more of a placeholder for a dynamic value which will be added later. As for the class names, I'll need to keep these, as they are part of our internal BEM-based framework, but I could definitely rework the JS a bit to tidy things up and make it leaner as you suggest.

Comment: Will hold off accepting for now in case there are any other answers here, but +1'd for the work :)

Comment: @wickywills Glad I could throw in my 2 cents. I thought so, that you're using BEM for creating class names. You could enhance the method I suggested to create the classes based on the level of nesting to keep it flexible.